# Segmentation Fault Error for a simple program in main() function

Tags: c, runtime-error

I just started teaching myself C, and wanted to write a basic program in main() that would take user input for a password, check it with the correct password, and have an appropriate output. However, the program started running and it read user input, but then it suddenly terminated under the error Segmentation Fault (code dumped). What's wrong with the code that's causing the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the password\n");
    char guess;
    scanf(" %c", &guess);
    char password[] = "Hello123";
    int correct = 0;

    while (correct != 1){
        if(strncmp(password,guess)==0){
            printf("Success! You have logged in with your password 
            %c\n",guess);
            correct +=1; 
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect password. Try again\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this compile? `strncmp` takes 3, not 2, arguments. Also you can't split a string literal among more than one line like that.

Comment: It compiles because there's no prototype for strncmp in OPs code. The compiler has no frame of reference so it assumes correctness. It's C :)

Comment: ...and 2 of `strncmp()`'s 3 args are `char*` not 1 `char*` and 1 `char`. Agree - a good compiler wouldn't have a bar of this!

Comment: [These are the warnings you should be getting](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f4cc05ca350f2d8). They should be treated as errors and *fixed* (not ignored or masked somehow).  If you're not getting those warnings, you're not cranking up your warning levels to high enough levels.

Comment: strncmp has 3 args in which first two are char* and third one is size.

Comment: You should also pass the number of chars equal to chars in guess or password as the 3rd argument to strncmp() as it checks that many chars while matching the two char arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I took a privilege of recoding your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *guess;
    const char password[] = "Hello123";
    int correct = 0;

    while (correct != 1){
        /*
         * Include the input prompt inside while loop
         */
        if (correct == 0){
            printf("Enter the password\n");
            scanf(" %s", guess);
        }

        if(strncmp(password,guess, 10)==0){ //strncmp accept 3 params, set length e.g 10
            printf("Success! You have logged in with your password %s\n",guess);
            correct = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect password. Try again\n");
            correct = 0;
        }
    }
}
```